# Oauth error invalid_request: Could not find Shopify API application with api_key Shopify error

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am receiving this error immediately after installing my app in my dev store when attempting to exchange the temporary access code for a permanent token.

Oauth error invalid_request: Could not find Shopify API application with api_key

I'm using below code

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request(
'POST', 
"https://{$store}/admin/oauth/access_token",
[
'form_params' => [
    'client_id' => $api_key,
    'client_secret' => $secret_key,
    'code' => $query['code']
]
]
);
$data = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContents(), true);
$access_token = $data['access_token'];
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!